# The best Hybrid framework to mobile development

Tags: mobile

I have been researching on Hybrid frameworks to use. I have seen some. but Now I am confused on which one to use. Phonegap versus xamarin versus codenameone. The html5 and js idea seems nice but I want to know is there any limitations to the html5 frameworks. codename one is one platform I would love cos it seemlessly goes on many devices but I am just confused now. I need advice.

Comment: Add Appverse to the list of possible candidates. BTW, maybe this would be a good topic for opening a wiki debate, evaluating pros and cons objectively.

Comment: Well bro, I just want to get advice that all so I know the right one. I am trying to start a debate @opalenzuela

Answer (score 0):

Codename One is a platform for writing Cross platform Native Mobile apps using Java.
I suggest you check it out at www.codenameone.com
There are other platforms out there that use c#, like Xamarin or Java script like Appcelerator. I guess it depends what environment your feel most comfortable with.

(Disclosure: I am affiliated with www.codenameone.com)